# Ansible - how to flatten a dict?

Tags: ansible

I've a nested dict:

```
  name:
  proxy:
    port:
    ip:
```

```
{
  "name": "dc01", 
  "proxy": {
    "port": 22, 
    "ip": "10.0.0.5/24"
  }
}
```

I'd like to flatten the dict, like this:

```
{
  "name": "dc01", 
  "port": 22, 
  "ip": "10.0.0.5/24"
}
```

I tried many things e.g. using `flatten` but didn't give me the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I overthought the problem..
Why not just get the relevant values by

```
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name,item.proxy['port'],item.proxy['ip'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ configuration }}"
```

It would be still interesting to know how to flatten the dict though